# Thread safety of += operator in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

Is the `+=` operator in c++ thread-safe?

It is possible to imagine a situation where it is not (Pseudocode):

```
int a = 5;

void thread1 () {
   a += 5;
}

void thread2 () {
   a += 5;
}

void main () {
    start_thread1 ();
    start_thread2 ();
    //Prints 15 always, but i think 10 is not impossible.
    printf ("%d\n", a);
}
```

It is obvious, that i must use Mutexes when += is overloaded, but do i have to set a mutex when working with simple types?

Comment: Start by writing valid C++.

Comment: Writing to the same (non-atomic) data from more than one thread is not "thread safe".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think adding all the pthread boilerplate code does not contribute to the quality of the question.

Comment: @Richard: Start by using the right prototype for main, and there's not that much boilerplate.

Comment: @Richard: Giving `main` the correct return type, including the needed headers, and writing semicolons at the end of statements certainly would. Then, in C++11, there is practically no boilerplate whatsoever for starting threads so you can easily present a compilable example in not much more code than this (if any!). Nobody writes pthread initialisation code any more... (since, what, 2001?!)

Comment: @Richard If you have access to a C++11 compiler you can use the threading facilites now included in the standard library. They provide a much simpler interface than pthreads (although not as comprehensive).

Comment: @Snps: In C++03, Boost.Threads. That has been convention for many, many years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is *not* thread-safe.

To get synchronized behaviour without using blocking (mutexes) you could e.g. use the C++11 wrapper `std::atomic`.

```
std::atomic<int> a{5};

void work() {
    a += 5; // Performed atomically.
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1{work};
    std::thread t2{work};

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout << a << std::endl; // Will always output 15.
}
```

Comment: Also note there is a typedef `std::atomic_int;`

Comment: Just note that this would probably make your `+=` operation a locked RMW

Answer (score 8):

`+=` is not atomic, so indeed it is not thread-safe and you could get `10`. Or, frankly, cows being ejected from the moon. Perhaps a pizza materialising around your dog's nose.

Comment: I will try the code.  My dog is hungry and I don't have any pizza.